# Can I build a bidirectional coroutine with Boost 1.55?

Tags: c++, boost, coroutine

The current Boost 1.55 implementation offers two kinds of [unidirectional coroutines](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/coroutine/coroutine/unidirect.html). One is a pull-type, which is a coroutine that takes no parameters and returns a value to the main context; the other is the push-type, which is a coroutine that accepts a parameter from the main context but returns no value.

How can I combine these two to create a bidirectional coroutine that both accepts a parameter and returns a value? On the surface it seems like it should be possible, but I can't quite figure out how to do it with the building blocks I have in `boost::coroutine`. There used to be a bidirectional coroutine in older Boosts, but it is now deprecated and undocumented, so I shouldn't rely on it.

ie, I would like something analogous to this:

```
void accumulate( pull_func &in, push_func &out )
{
  int x = 0;
  while ( in ) 
  {
    x += in.get() ; // transfers control from main context 
    out(x); // yields control to main context
  }
}

void caller( int n ) 
{
   bidirectional_coro( accumulate );
   for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i )
   {
      int y = accumulate(i); 
      printf( "%d ", y ); // "0 1 3 6 10" etc
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, boost coroutine was bidirectional when it was first included in boost(1.53 I think).

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0_beta1/libs/coroutine/doc/html/coroutine/coroutine.htm

That code should still be compatible with the most recent version of boost, with minor modification if anything.

Also, you could use boost::context directly to create your own coroutine class.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/context/doc/html/index.html

The parameter 'intptr_t vp' of fcontext_swap can be use to pass values/pointers back and forth, or you could store values in the coroutine itself, as member variables of your coroutine class should be valid from both contexts.

**edit:**

The short answer to your original question is no. What you are asking cannot be done. Each coroutine has it's own stack and context, which are not accessible from other coroutine instances. Also, when you jump into the coroutine's context, the state of the calling context is stored in **that** coroutine instance, and a jump back to the original context can only be made by calling into the argument that **that** coroutine passed into your function.

But, variables declared outside the local scope of the coroutine will be valid from inside and outside the coroutine function. So you could use a coroutine::push_type, and push a pointer instead of a value. You could use the value, and then modify it before jumping back to the original context.

Also, you can safely pass pointers to local variables into the coroutine, since they won't be destroyed until you jump back out of the coroutine and run the calling scope to completion.

Comment: Boost 1.55 docs say that the bidirectional coroutine code is deprecated. (In fact, that's all they say about it; it's otherwise totally undescribed.) Are they safe to use anyway?

Comment: Too many users have used the bidirectional interface in the wrong way - for instance the users did not know when they have to pass an argument to the ctor of coroutine and when not. With the unidirectional interface the dataflow is clear.

Comment: @Crashworks: I don't know exactly why bidirectional coroutines were deprecated, but I can see how what olk is saying could be true. It's probably safe to use, but it's not maintained, so you would have to fix any new bugs you found on your own. Also, see my edit for more details why what you are asking won't work, and a suggested workaround.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as "No. You can't do this with `boost::coroutine `. However, you can build your own thing out of boost::context instead to accomplish what you need."

Comment: this comment seems to imply that my answer contains incorrect information. If so, please let me know so I can correct it.

Comment: @bitwise Your answer is correct -- it just answers a bit more than I was actually asking. So I was just clarifying the parts that directly address the question. But the rest of the information should remain in place because it will be useful to others who come across this question.

Comment: @Crashworks a couple of links that may interest you: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUhSjfSbINE#t=1049 -- and the proposal: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3858.pdf

Answer (score 1):

you could look at the example contained in boost.coroutine
https://github.com/boostorg/coroutine/blob/master/example/cpp03/chaining.cpp

Comment: That's not quite the same thing -- that example shows how one pull coroutine can in turn call another pull coroutine for input. What I'm looking for is a way for one coroutine to both pull and push to the same context.

Comment: If you can't adapt the example for your needs then I've to say it is not possible. The only way would be to pass an parameter which is able to store a reference or pointer to the coroutine-fn.